# Phone authentication is not working after i generate the signed apk in Andriod

Tags: android, authentication

I am using the phone authentication in my app as the login page.
I have generated the signed apk for it.
My app is not working and otp is not getting for the app.
I have generated the SHA key and kept it in my database through the signing report.When once i generated apk to release the app into the Playstore it is not working.

Please help me out,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Authentication to sign in a user by sending an SMS message to the user's phone. The user signs in using a one-time code contained in the SMS message.

Before you begin

1. Add Firebase to your Android project.
2. Add the dependency for Firebase Authentication to your app-level build.gradle file:

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'**

3. If you haven't yet connected your app to your Firebase project, do so from the Firebase console.
4. If you haven't already set your app's SHA-1 hash in the Firebase console, do so.  See Authenticating Your Client for information about finding your app's SHA-1 hash.

*Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator.*

Comment: My database is firestore only i also  added the SHA key in the project settings under the id of my project.Its working when iam running in my system.When i genrated apk it is not working.

Comment: Iam not getting the otp when i installed my app through the signed apk.It is working fine before the generation of apk.

Comment: Can you grab logcat?

Comment: how i grab the logcat beacuse it is through apk. App is working perfectly when it is connected through phone.

Comment: did u created it in Android Studio or Eclipse?  Check if you have signed properly apk and check 2 options when u create apk. new Android  Studio has that option

Comment: created in the andriod studio and also ticked both the options while signing the apk